# How to re-populate the form when CodeIgniter form validation detects error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to populate all my input fields when the CodeIgniter form validation detects an error,

Here's my input form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin.php/country/add_country" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          <fieldset>
                            <legend><?php if(isset($msg)) echo $msg;?>
                            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?></legend>
                            <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Country Name</label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="title" class="span6 typeahead" id="title"  data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" value="<?php echo set_value('title');?>">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">ISO2 Code</label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="iso2" class="span6 typeahead" id="iso2"  data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" value="<?php echo set_value('iso2');?>" >
                              </div>
                            </div>
                                                        <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">ISO3 Code</label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="iso3" class="span6 typeahead" id="iso3"  data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" value="<?php echo set_value('iso3');?>">
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-actions">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                              <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                          </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

Here's my setup_rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Country Name', 'required|min_length[5]|alpha');
```

Now when I am getting error, the form is populating only the value title field, it's not populating other fields.

Comment: if you apply validation on other field than it will work for other field also

Comment: i dont want validation on other fields

Comment: if you don't want validation than set value in POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you apply validation on other field than it will work for other field also.

try something like this.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Country Name', 'required|min_length[5]|alpha');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('iso2', 'ISO2 Code', 'min_length[5]|alpha');// any validation you want.
$this->form_validation->set_rules('iso3', 'ISO3 Code', 'min_length[5]|alpha');// any validation you want.
```